Nginx requests forwarding downloads the page
Problem:
I have a server from hetzner (linux cloud). I have installed cloudpanel to manage easier the websites. I have a website that lives in the subdomain api.website.com where I provide few API's.
The thing is that I have multiple projects there which are living each in a subfolder like:

api.website.com/project1/
api.website.com/project2/
api.website.com/project3/

Each of the projects folder, has its own composer.json file and is a separate project.
I have tried to modify the vHost file to forward each folders request to its respective index.php.
Here my vHosts code:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  http3 off;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name api.website.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

   location /project1/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/index.php?$args;
   }

  location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map|mjs)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header alt-svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name api.website.com;
  {{root}}

  include /etc/nginx/global_settings;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

So with this line I try to forward each request going through /project1/ to its /project1/index.php. The result is it downloads a file by visiting any api.
API example: https://api.website.com/project1/todos/all
I am using this repo/package to manage routings: https://github.com/steampixel/simplePHPRouter
Worth also to mention, in Apache it was really easy to do it through .htaccess. All I needed to do was just add the file to the respective folder. Here the example file:
DirectoryIndex index.php

# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# set your rewrite base
# Edit this in your init method too if you script lives in a subfolder
RewriteBase /project1/

# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 
# Push every request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]

